# Muitliple fields in options from collection select text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

How can i get 2 fields to display as the text for this rails select statement:

`<%= select_tag "test3", options_from_collection_for_select(Teamplayer.joins(:live_player), "playerid", :name) %>`

So instead of just John Doe, i get John Doe Maryland

In other words instead of Player, i get Player College

Answer (score 0):

For eg, if you want the name and location to be displayed in the select options, you should do

```
<%= select_tag "test3", options_for_select(Teamplayer.joins(:live_player).where(:teamid => @ids).collect{|p| "#{p.name} #{p.location}"}) %>
```

Comment: ok that sort of worked. Now it says wrong number of arguments: `<%= select_tag "test3", options_from_collection_for_select(Teamplayer.joins(:live_player).where(:teamid => @ids).all.collect{|p| "#{p.Plyr} #{p.Team}"}) %>`

Comment: wrong number of arguments where? show me the full error

Comment: after that it said `(1 of 3)` that was the whole error